# Jquery ajax wont send POST variables to php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

EDIT: I now understand that in order to redirect i need to use ajax depending on the response i get from php thanks to ADyson. Best answer,thanks dude and thanks everyone for their help.

I've been trying to make a simple login form on PHP sending POST request variables to PHP and authenticating with MySQL. I have tried everything such as configuring xampp, putting htaccess file in the same folder, tried various ajax syntax but it's still not working. I made it so simple so I can debug easily. The problem is the success function is firing but the post variables aren't being sent to the location header won't go to register.php. Here is the code:

PHP

```
<?php
    require_once 'dbconnect.php';

    if (isset($_POST['nickname']) && !empty($_POST['nickname'])) {
        $nickname = $_POST['nickname'];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $password = $_POST['password'];
    }

    $sql = "SELECT nickname,password FROM users WHERE nickname = '$nickname' and password = '$password'";

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($count == 1) {

        header('location:register.php');

    } else {
        header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
    }
?>
```

JS

```
$("#submitBtn").on("click",function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"dologin.php", 
        data:{nickname:"alex",password:"123"},
        success:function(){
        alert("skata");
    }});
});
```

Comment: `isset($_POST['nickname']) && !empty($_POST['nickname'])` is redundant, since `empty()` already performs `!isset()`

Comment: If you want to redirect the user, why are you using ajax over a simple form submission?

Comment: Are you saying `$count==1` is never true?  The `header(location)` line is likely a red-herring as you can't redirect using ajax that way

Comment: redirection should be in the ajax, you aren't returning any response actually

Comment: _“so the location header wont go to register.php”_ - even if your PHP script _did_ issue the correct location header, this would not redirect your frontend - _because_ you are making a background request. If anything, you would have to send some info back to the JS part, so that _that_ can then decide to navigate elsewhere on the client side.

Comment: "the post variables arent being sent so the location header wont go to register.php"...these two things are not related, as CBroe hints. Are you **sure** the POST values really aren't being sent? How did you verify that, exactly? All that part could succeed and it still wouldn't redirect you, because you can't redirect from an AJAX request. In fact the _whole point_ of AJAX is to allow you to _stay on the same page_, and not require redirects. If you want to do a redirect, use a normal form postback instead of AJAX.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Also, please don't store passwords in plain text - that is another security risk. Learn about [password hashing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) instead.

Comment: Guys i know the code is simple and i shouldnt put text like that im just making simple to understand what i want to do. Im sure post doesnt work since Im getting undefined index if i go to dologin.php

Comment: data  object should have strings for both the property names and values .. eg:    data: "{ "nickname":"alex"}"

What works better is serializing the entire form thouigh `$("form").serialize()`

Comment: Also im using ajax so that i can handle errors

Comment: I have already tried form.serialize() and it doesnt work unfortunately

Comment: @mike510a that's not the case, you only need a string for the name if it's a keyword or some other requirement such as spaces (why would you?)

Comment: @mike510a that is incorrect, sorry

Comment: @mrgatos "Im sure post doesnt work since Im getting undefined index if i go to dologin.php"...what do you mean by "go to" dologin.php exactly? If you just visit it in your browser, then that would cause a GET request, and no parameters would be passed. So naturally that would fail. The correct way to check if your variables are being sent in the AJAX request would be to watch that request in your browser's Network Tool. Also, have you tried just posting a HTML form directly to dologin.php? Please show us your form, anyway, so we can understand why serialize() also might not be working.

Comment: @mrgatos You seem to have two *separate* issues.  *"The problem is the success function is firing"* - the success function is firing because you're not returning an error.    *"the post variables aren't being sent ... **so**... the location header wont go to register.php"* - these are two different issues - you have only confirmed that the post variables "aren't being sent" *because* it doesn't redirect - but it doesn't redirect because that's not how you redirect via ajax.  SO are the variables being sent?  If so, fix the 2nd issue, if not, fix the 1st issue **and** the 2nd issue.

Comment: Re your edit: If you found a solution, please post it as an Answer below, including the modifications you have made to your code, so everyone can clearly see it, and they can upvote it, and future users can find it in searches (questions with accepted answers score much higher in search rankings) so everyone can benefit. You're allowed - and encouraged - to answer your own question. (And the answer is _not_ a part of the question, so should not be included there. This site follows a clear Q&A format, so don't mix the two parts together please.)

Comment: Caching of previous PHP output could be an issue depending on the web server configuration

Comment: Also you can't do header("location:") from an AJAX call like that.. you have to return something from the PHP script, redirections wont work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

### * WARNING *

Before considering this answer as a good way to implement a login page, you should consider the fact that you have not implemented any methods of securing said page from a wide range of attacks, many of which will allow for hackers and bots to execute arbitrary code in your database and/or in other parts of the site using XSS.

All a hacker would have to do is define 'password' to be an SQL injection that modifies the database and you can possibly reveal your entire database's contents to the hacker.

Also, plaintext passwords are not a good way to store login data, instead use a password hash.

You may also consider using nonce to prevent XSRF attacks and also some sort of brute force password hacking / DoS protection mechanism would be wise.

---

With that being said, here's a way to make your password form work

You can't do a redirection as part of an ajax request that can interact with the request that makes the ajax call.  The two contexts are different.

What you *CAN* do is return a value from the PHP script like this:

```
   <?php 
       require_once 'dbconnect.php';

    if(isset($_POST['nickname']) && !empty($_POST['nickname'])) { $nickname =  $_POST['nickname']; }

    if(isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) { $password = $_POST['password']; }

    $sql = "SELECT nickname,password FROM users WHERE nickname = '$nickname' and password = '$password'";

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql); $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($count==1){
         print_r("true");
    } else{
        print_r("false");   
     } ?>
```

combined with a way of parsing the output

```
$("#submitBtn").on("click",function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"dologin.php", 
        data:{nickname:"alex",password:"123"},
        success:function(result){
            if (result == "true") {
                window.location.href = "register.php";
            }

    }});
});
```

Answer (score -2):

What you can do is take data from the php file

`success:function(data){
    console.log(data);
}`

Please also check whether query is returning you exactly one row ? I also don't know whether or not your dbconnect.php works.

Comment: Since the PHP never echoes anything this won't be useful. More alterations would be required. Also you've entirely missed the point about redirections and AJAX. This post reads more like suggestions for debugging than an actual solution to the problem. once you have 50 reputation, you'll be able to post comments. Until then, don't use the Answers feature to post suggestions (rather than solutions).